# How do I isolate "tokens" into individual variables

Tags: java, token

I've been trying to teach myself Java for a few months.  I'm tired of the books that teach you how to say "hello" and little else IMO.

Here is my question, I want to read a "tab delimited" text file into specific fields.  Some of the fields are int, some Strings, and some are int[] arrays.  (I find it hard to believe it is this hard to read a simple file!)

How do I get the tokens variable where the first token in a record(line) is "int", second is "String", 3 thru 5 are separate "int" and the next 21 are to be in an "int" array[]?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
package viewOfGolfSystem;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

class TextDataCheck {
    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                "TXT and CSV files", "txt", "csv");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();

        String filename = f.getAbsolutePath();
            // should return the filename(i.e.path)

        FileReader flr = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner sInput = new Scanner(flr).useDelimiter("\t");

        while (sInput.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(sInput.next());
            }
        sInput.close();

        } else {
            System.out
            .println("File chosen is not an approved option.  Try again\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the route you want to go, and the flexibility you need you could write some code yourself, and examples of such code can be found on hundreds of sites, eg [on this blog](http://sanjaal.com/java/tag/java-tab-delimited-file-read-sample-example/).  The core of the code they propose is this:

```
    BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader(dataFileName));

    String line;

    /**
     * Looping the read block until all lines in the file are read.
     */
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

        /**
         * Splitting the content of tabbed separated line
         */
        String datavalue[] = line.split("\t");
        String value1 = datavalue[0];
        String value2 = datavalue[1];
        int value3 = Integer.parseInt(datavalue[2]);
        double value4 = Double.parseDouble(datavalue[3]);

        /**
         * Printing the value read from file to the console
         */
        System.out.println(value1 + "\t" + value2 + "\t" + value3 + "\t"
                + value4);
    }
    bReader.close();
```

Should be easily adapted to your purposes.

Now, an entirely different route would be to use an existing general purpose flatfile parser like [JSAPar](https://github.com/org-tigris-jsapar/jsapar).  The beauty of that solution is that the entire conversion is driven by a configuration file, so if tomorrow you want to change the file format it will be easier to adapt your program.  Of course nothing is free, it will take some time to learn such a library, and it adds extra size to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
private static class Thing {

    private final int int1;
    private final String string2;
    private final int int3;
    private final int int4;
    private final int int5;
    private final int[] int21;

    public Thing(final String[] line) {
        int1 = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);
        string2 = line[1];
        int3 = Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
        int4 = Integer.parseInt(line[3]);
        int5 = Integer.parseInt(line[4]);
        int21 = new int[21];
        for (int i = 0; i < 21; ++i) {
            int21[i] = Integer.parseInt(line[i - 5]);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myFile.txt"));
    final List<Thing> myThings = new LinkedList<Thing>();
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            myThings.add(new Thing(line.split("\t")));
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Read your file line by line and then split on `\t`.

Create a class that takes a `String[]` and parses it to your required values.

Obviously this doesn't take account of delimiters and escape characters, in order to do that you would need a much more sophisticated parsing method. It would probably be easier to use an existing library like [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).